# IE iframe 1px border to the right

Tags: iframe

Please look at http://www.mymix947.com
In the header I have a 1px border to the right of the banner. 
You will see a black line dividing the banner and listen live button.

This is an iframe and I can't seem to eliminate the line.

This seems to only happen with Windows 7 - IE Browser 8.0.7

When my browser is full screen - I don't see it, but if I shrink the browser slightly - the line is there.

Comment: Wrong forum. Try stackoverflow.com

Comment: @TFM: please don't just tell people to post on another Trilogy site; you should inform them that their question can be migrated.

Comment: this question is more appropriate to our sister site Stack Overflow; it will be migrated there shortly.  you will need to register an account on both sites and associate your accounts together in order to regain ownership of the migrated question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it in these browsers on Windows 7:

- Firefox 3.6.3
- IE 8.0.7
- IE 8.0.7 in compatibility mode
- IE 7

Since I am unable to replicate the problem as stated in these browsers it be full screen or not, you should check if the problem isn't on your computer only or perhaps has something to do with add-ons on your system.

Try looking on another PC if the problem occurs there.